# stored procedure(postgresql) and jdbc results are different

Tags: java, postgresql-9.1, numeric

I have a stored procedure which returns numeric, when i run it on db(posgtresql 9.1), result is 367,52. but when i run it on java, result(resultset.getString) is 367,50

it's not happening always. most of the times the results are same however sometimes the results are different.

my jdbc driver: postgresql-9.1-903.jdbc3.jar.
java: jdk 6

function is very big, it calculates with double precision values, then cast them numeric values. 
in db:

```
SELECT function::numeric from function(bigint parameter)
```

in java;

```
PreparedStatement ps=conn.prepareStatement("SELECT function::numeric from function(bigint parameter)");
ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();

if(rs.next()){
  System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
}
```

Comment: can you share query and code ?

Comment: `I have a stored procedure` then share it.

Comment: If your result is numeric then why do you use `getString()` - that doesn't make sense. You should use `getBigDecimal()` instead. And you don't need a `from`, just run: `SELECT function(bigint parameter)`

Comment: i tried every getXX, but the results are not the same as db. float367.5
double367.5
sting367.4999999999999968
stingBig367.4999999999999968
thanks your advice @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: If you are using `float` or `double precision` in the stored procedure then this is to be expected. Those aren't exact numbers (please read the manual, it's explained there). You should use `numeric(...)` instead.

Comment: thanks @a_horse_with_no_name, but i can't change types of columns to numeric. 
the real question is, why are the results different? its not important real result, it can be 367.52 or 367.50. it is important that, they must be same on java-postgresql db.

Answer (score 0):

i changed my jdbc driver to postgresql-8.2-508.jdbc2ee.jar and the problem solved.